# How can I get the "strip input" toolbar in the Movie Clip Editor?

Tags: edit-mode, video

Could anyone please help me with this one? I can't see this small plus icon (png file attached). 
[image]I just don't have it! And the result is that I don't have this toolbar: STRIP INPUT. I can squize image or video or change dimension, but I would like to change "working area" (Idk if it is a proper name for it, but my image or video has a black area surrounding I can't remove). 
I have check all toolbars but still no clue what to do and how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update to 2.82a: https://www.blender.org/download/
In the View Menu you'll find it: 
[image]

For making the video fit the preview area, use this:
[image]